# Can send mail to users on server, but not from remote email

Tags: sendmail, mx-record

I am setting up sendmail.

I have added mx records for my domain, such as mail.domain.org, and domain.org. I did this a few hours ago.

I can send an email to a virtual email from the server, but not from an email on another server.

Looking at /var/log/maillog, no connection is even incoming or attempted.

Do I need to wait longer for mx records to propagate across the dns universe?

Or is there something I could check to see if it is configured correctly on my end?

Additionally, when I try to add the user account, and use the imap server mail.domain.org, it doesn't make a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sendmail: Can not receive external mail

Is you sendmail daemon listing for SMTP connections **only** on loopback interface (127.0.0.1)?

```
netstat -ant | grep :25
```

### Fix

https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/general_issues_faq/#4.22
Why can't I receive external mail?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. Running that command returns: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

Comment: I'm guessing it should say smtp somewhere in there for the daemon so I'm assuming it isn't.

Comment: It seems your sendmail accepts only SMTP connections from itself ('127.0.0.1:25') as described in the FAQ entry.

Comment: Quite right you were! I changed my daemonportoptions line in sendmail.cf from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 and it is now accepting remote emails. Cheers